# HTML Custom List Ordering (alphabetic list with non-english characters)

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to create an ordered list such as below.

> a. Item 1
>
> b. Item 2
>
> c. Item 3
>
> ç. Item 4
>
> ...

I thought normally the markup below should do what I want:

```
<ol type="a">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li value="ç">Item 4</li>
    ...
</ol>
```

But it doesn't seem to have an effect, it is just giving me the regular ordering "a,b,c,d..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, lists don't work like that. With a `list-style-type` of `lower-latin`, only the lowercase latin letters will be displayed. After "z", it continues with "aa" and so on.

However, it's perfectly possible to do what you want with a bit of customised CSS.

```css
li[value] {list-style-type:none; position:relative}
li[value]::before {content:attr(value) '. ';
position:absolute; right:calc(100% + .33em);}
```

```html
<ol type="a">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li value="ç">Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ol>
```

---

Sorry, the above solution only works because the `value` attribute is a non-numerical value. If you put `value="9"` or something, it will interfere with the numbering of the rest of the list: the next item will have the value 10 and it will get "j." as a list marker!

So a better solution is to leave the `value` alone and use a `data` attribute instead. `data-marker` or something. Then the rest of the list will not suffer any consequences.

```css
li[data-marker] {list-style-type:none; position:relative}
li[data-marker]::before {content:attr(data-marker) '. ';
position:absolute; right:calc(100% + .33em);}
```

```html
<ol type="a">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li data-marker="ç">Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ol>
```

On another note: if your intention is to insert accented letters in between the unaccented ones, for instance if the list should look like a, b, c, ç, d etc, then you *will* need to use `value` in order to make the list come out right. The list items that are out of order will need to be re-synced!

```css
li[data-marker] {list-style-type:none; position:relative}
li[data-marker]::before {content:attr(data-marker) '. ';
position:absolute; right:calc(100% + .33em);}
```

```html
<ol type="a">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li data-marker="ç" value="3">Item 4</li> <!-- Items 3 & 4 both get value 3 for "c" -->
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @panush Note that what I had at first was not complete; it may cause you to run into problems. See the revised version for the pitfalls and the solutions to those.