# Show ordered list in Russian alphabets/numerics

Tags: html, css

Below is the sample code I've wrote. I tried searching but not sure how to show Russian alphabet or Russian numbers in ordered list HTML.

I gone through this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type but I couldn't find `cyrillic` or `Russian`.

(I really don't want to handle this using JavaScript, unless if there is no other way.)

```css
.russia {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap&subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">

<ol class="russia">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Babe</li>
  <li>Carrots</li>
  <li>Dungeon</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Do you need to be able to handle any length of list, or is there an upper limit on the number of items?

Comment: @JordanRunning I don't have any fixed sets. We're developing a Russian website, so I thought of handling this in some native way.

Comment: I don't think there's currently a way to do this with only CSS in all browsers. The [`symbols()` CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/symbols) would do the trick but it's currently only [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_list-style_symbols) in Firefox. I'd check out the related question and its answers linked to by @sodimel above.

Comment: Another related question with an alternative approach (no JavaScript, but additional markup): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082868/html-custom-list-ordering-alphabetic-list-with-non-english-characters